# Does Azure SQL support heaps or does it still require clustered indexes?

Tags: azure-sql-database, clustered-index, heap-table

I have found lots of old documentation, like this [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/why-do-i-need-a-clustered-index/) dating to 2010, about how SQL Azure requires clustered indexes and doesn't support tables which don't have them.

However, is that still the case, after 10 years? I cannot find any clear, more recent documentation.

This 2016 [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) talks about "Heaps (Tables without Clustered Indexes)" and applies to both SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. I would therefore guess that tables without clustered indexes are now supported. Is that the case? I would have liked to see it documented it more clearly.

Note this is not a generic software recommendation request - it is a very factual yes or no type of question.

Answer (score 5):

The 10-year old docs relate to the older "V11" architecture for SQL Azure.  The "V12" architecture, which has been in place for many years, supports heaps, clustered indexes, in-memory tables, etc.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, Heap Tables are currently supported**.  Documentation linked below shows them supported by Azure SQL Database (original scope of the question), SQL Server and Azure SQL Managed Instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score -2):

SQL Azure requires every table to have at least one clustered index in order to maintain the replicas which are created out of the box for dbs.

Comment: According to other replies, clustered indices were required only up to v11. Are you saying this is not true?

Comment: Recently we are doing POC to deploy database to Azure using SQL Server Project and "Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx" package. We used Northwind database, one of the table "[dbo].[Region]" did not had clustered index. During compilation, we got this error, "SQL71560: Table [dbo].[Region] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server." Our SQL Server Project Target Platform was set to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database".

Comment: Which version of Azure was that?

Comment: I think, database compatibility Level as SQL Server 2017 (140)